# [__NSCFString zOrder]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, singleton

Never met this one before, has anyone faced a crash error with the following log?

```
-[__NSCFString zOrder]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11da100
```

For some reason it crashes at this line:

```
    [[MMClass alloc] init];
```

My singleton class implementation looks like:

```
static id instance = nil;

+ (MMClass *)sharedInstance {

    @synchronized([MMClass class])
    {
        if (!instance)
            [[MMClass alloc] init];
        return instance;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Show `[MMClass init]`.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Thanks for pointing me to the direction. It was a simple thing, I missed that one. I don't know why but it happens, sometimes...

Comment: The answer provided by Marcelo Fabri solves another issue you have in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not assigning the initialized object to your variable. Also, the most recommended way to create a singleton is:

```
+ (MMClass *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static MMClass* _sharedInstance = nil;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[MMClass alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: Probably there's some garbage value on your variable. As Nikolai suggested, take a look where you're calling zOrder to check the object.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the problem is a message `zOrder` being sent to an `NSString`. You should search you project for `zOrder` messages.

Also, Xcode should pinpoint the problematic code when running in the debugger and setting an exception breakpoint.